# how to add pages to an existing pdf

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, foxit-reader, pdfedit

Hi I am using Foxit Reader 7.3.0.118 , I Select Create PDF.
Select From Scanner.
Hit Scan.
after scanning 30 pages I have saved a document.

1) Now let us say I want to add 31st page to above document then how to add pages scanned via scanner to above saved pdf?

There is an option in this version of Foxit which says from scanner but that option creates a new pdf rather than adding to an existing pdf. So I would like to know if I missed something or there is an option if it exists then let me know how it works.

2) Also the files scanned I am getting very heavy in size the pdf is 500 mb how to compress this heavy pdf.
I use Windows 8.

Comment: Foxit reader is a reader, it probably doesn't have editing functionality. Try to look for a pdf editor instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sejda allows [compressing PDF files](https://www.sejda.com/compress-pdf) and [adding an additional page](https://sejda.com/merge-pdf) (by merging the original document with a new page). If you have the new page as a scanned image, you can [convert the image to a pdf document](https://www.sejda.com/jpg-to-pdf).

All these operations can be done online or offline. If you'd prefer to work locally on your computer, there is a [Sejda Desktop](https://www.sejda.com/desktop) application available.

[image: compress pdf]
[image: merge pdf]

Answer (score 0):

Foxit Reader does not allow later editing of PDFs, therefore it does not support adding an additional page. You can use Foxit PDF editor to do that, or another free PDF editor.

As for the size, there are a lot of tools that can compress a pdf to acceptable size; some you can use directly online: http://www.ilovepdf.com/compress_pdf

Comment: I have 500mb file and data plan is limited to I can not upload files on internet each time to compress so I need a permanent solution to compress files.

Comment: Then you can get an application that compacts it offline. Check multiple choices here: http://www.wikihow.com/Reduce-PDF-File-Size